# Minimize and Normalize winform from console application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I have two separate processes- one is a console application and one is a winform application.  Now, if the winform is minimized then the console application should normalize it and vice versa. How can i do this? Also, the console application starts the winform and on start it should be in its normalized position. How can i go about this on the following lines

```
     var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyWinformApp");
                if (processes.Length == 0)
                {
                    Process.Start("MyWinformApp.exe");
    How to be sure that the winform will open up in Normalized state
                }
                else 
                {
                    IntPtr handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
    //If winform minimized the normalize and vice versa ....What to do here
//Maybe use GetWindowPlacement 
?? 
handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
            if(if winform was minimized) //how to find this???
            {
                ShowWindow(handle, Normal);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowWindow(handle, Minimize);
            }

                }
```

I did find information on pinvoke.net but was confused so would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does that and the other part of the question was answered by DeeMac above

```
 #region For getting the hadnle and min/max operation
        private const int SW_Minimize  = 6;
        private const int SW_Normal    = 1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        private static WINDOWPLACEMENT GetPlacement(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
            placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
            GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref placement);
            return placement;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(
            IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [Serializable]
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public ShowWindowCommands showCmd;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
        }

        internal enum ShowWindowCommands : int
        {
            Hide = 0,
            Normal = 1,
            Minimized = 2,
            Maximized = 3,
        }
        #endregion


 var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyWinformApp");
                if (processes.Length == 0)
                {
                    Process.Start("MyWinformApp.exe");
                }
                else 
                {
                    IntPtr handle = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
                    var placement = GetPlacement(handle);
                    if (String.Equals(placement.showCmd.ToString(), "Minimized")) 
                    {
                        ShowWindow(handle, SW_Normal);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ShowWindow(handle, SW_Minimize);
                    }

                }
```